# Is it possible to exclude a directory with ProxyPassReverse?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, proxypass

I'm looking to exclude a directory from a site is behind a reverse proxy.

examples I'm seeing are using ! , but I haven't been able to solve this

See examples that I've tried below.

Legacy system using mod_proxy module located in httpd.conf (just how it was setup before I took it over)

Examples:

```
  1st test: 
     ProxyPass /site/test ! http://prod-test.azurewebsites.net/site
     ProxyPassReverse /site/test ! http://prod-test.azurewebsites.net/site

  2nd test: 
     ProxyPass /site/test ! 
     ProxyPass /site/test ! http://prod-test.azurewebsites.net/site
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: What scope in apache are you applying those directives?  It can be applied at different levels server, vhost, and directory.  I suspect you might be able to put a more specific scoped block in your config that would override.  But I am not certain.

Comment: I have the ProxyPass listed after my last IfModule in the httpd.conf files

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault! It might be possible. However, I think it is a better idea to learn the mod_rewrite. Yes, it is... cryptic, but you should do it only once. After that, all such tasks will be easy, trivial.

Comment: The problem is that this is only temporary until we get our App Gateway setup. It(unix box) being very outdated, I'm hesitant to try anything new, as it may break something that I'm not aware of.